# windows 7 - protect folder from re(moving/naming)

Tags: windows-7

My computer is sometimes used by multiple users (younger ones :P), sometimes they move, rename or accidently remove a folder in the desktop folder. I want to prevent this, is there a way to do this?

notice: The content of the folder is updated daily

Comment: One simply way would be to modify the user's permissions as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

```
create a new user **kids**
make it a **standard user** account.
set either no password or easy password.

Password protect your account.
```

They can log in and mess around without breaking things. In fact, I recommend each of them have there own user account.